# why "for loop in" failed to apply .remove() method at 6th and 8th index of an existing list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to apply `remove.()` method on a list of strings using `for loop in`, but the `for loop in` keep keeping index `6` and `8` of the list.

I was able to solve the problem by applying the `for loop in` on a sorted(list) and by using `while True` statement. But still, I can't explain why it will skip an index if I just try `for loop in` on the unsorted list as shown below.

Any explanation, please?

```
birds=["cockatoo", "turkey", "hawk", "chicken", "dove", "crow", "canary", "chaffinch", "cardinal"]
print("birds list before: ", birds) 
print()

for bird in birds:
    if bird.startswith("c"):
        birds.remove(bird) 
    else:
        pass 
print("birds list after: ", birds)


#expected output: 

birds list before: ['cockatoo', 'turkey', 'hawk', 'chicken', 'dove', 'crow', 'canary', 'chaffinch', 'cardinal']

birds list after: ['turkey', 'hawk', 'dove']


#actual output: 

birds list before: ['cockatoo', 'turkey', 'hawk', 'chicken', 'dove', 'crow', 'canary', 'chaffinch', 'cardinal']

birds list after: ['turkey', 'hawk', 'dove', 'canary', 'cardinal']
```

Comment: Can you add the same words in a different position so that we can see if its actually a problem with the index or the word itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this up so you can see the problem immediately:

```
birds=["cockatoo", "turkey", "hawk", "chicken", "dove", "crow", "canary", 
"chaffinch", "cardinal"]
print("birds list before: ", birds) 
print()

for bird in birds:
    print(bird)               # I have added this
    if bird.startswith("c"):
        birds.remove(bird) 
    else:
        pass 
print("birds list after: ", birds)
```

Which outputs

```
birds list before:  ['cockatoo', 'turkey', 'hawk', 'chicken', 'dove', 'crow', 'canary', 'chaffinch', 'cardinal']

cockatoo
hawk
chicken
crow
chaffinch
birds list after:  ['turkey', 'hawk', 'dove', 'canary', 'cardinal']
```

Do you notice how the birds printed is missing some of the elements? This is because you have removed some of the elements from the list you are iterating over before it got to them. This actually shows some of the implementation of the 'for x in array' loop, it is just using the next

A simple solution for this is change `for bird in birds:` to `for bird in list(birds):` this creates a copy of the list.

sorted creates a copy of the list just like I just did, so when you say to remove the element the sorted list still has all of the elements in it, the birds list hasn't.

To give a better understanding of this look at this:

```
birds=["cockatoo", "turkey", "hawk", "chicken", "dove", "crow", "canary", "chaffinch", "cardinal"]
my_iter = iter(birds)
print(next(my_iter))
birds.remove("turkey")
print(next(my_iter))
```

which outputs:

```
cockatoo
hawk
```

despite "turkey" coming next

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this bug is being caused because you're modifying your list while iterating through it. This should generally be avoided!

Two other ways to approach this are with:

A while loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(birds):
    if birds[i].startswith("c"):
        del birds[i]
    else:
        i += 1
print("birds list after: ", birds)
```

A filter:

```
birds = filter(lambda bird: not bird.startswith("c"), birds)
print("birds list after: ", birds)
```

A list comprehension according to Victor Aguiar:

```
birds = [i for i in birds if i.startswith('c') == False]
print("birds list after: ", birds)
```

Take a look at this article for more details: 
https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/

Comment: Another way:

bird = [i for i in birds if i.startswith('c') == False]

Comment: Since you have the index already, you can just use `del birds[i]`, rather than `birds.remove(bird)` (which has to search for the first reference to `bird` in the list).

Comment: Thank you, although I assumed I don't know the index. hence wont be using **del birds[i]